# TinyMCE with Html.TextAreaFor() outputs into quotation marks

Tags: html, model-view-controller, razor, tinymce

I'm using the TinyMCE editor to add some HTML to some posts in my application. I'm using a textarea as such:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body, new { id = "createPost" })
```

...and my script looks like:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#createPost'
});
```

...with a few other things in the script for adding the toolbar and setting the height of the textarea. Anyway, when I try to make a post, the output has the HTML tags displayed in the output rather than applying them and stylizing the text, i.e. saying `<strong>this</strong>` would look just like it did there rather than like **this**. I noticed in my Inspect>Elements tab that it's being rendered inside a paragraph tag as expected, but the whole thing (inside the `<p>`) is wrapped in quotation marks.

I've read elsewhere that you can't have HTML inside a textarea, but they are using a textarea in the official quick start guide for TinyMCE, so I'm not sure what's what.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use "htmlentities" to validate your post form?
if so, html format will lost.

check this

```
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php
```

use sql injection instead of htmlentities.
try the output of htmlentities, so you can see it.

```
https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_string_htmlentities
```

Comment: HI @apsara welcome to SO, please post the code directly here, as link only answers might become invalid if the page's URL changes.Also while posting links use the hyperlink to paste the urls instead of code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Did some more digging - turns out it wasn't anything to do with my creating posts, it was the displaying them that was the problem (which makes total sense now). I was using `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Body)` which doesn't allow HTML injection. I changed it to `@Html.Raw(Model.Body)` and all is well.